# spark structured streaming file source read from a certain partition onwards

Tags: scala, file, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, partition

I have a folder on HDFS like below containing ORC files:

```
/path/to/my_folder
```

It contains partitions:

```
/path/to/my_folder/dt=20190101
/path/to/my_folder/dt=20190103
/path/to/my_folder/dt=20190103
...
```

Now I need to process the data here using streaming.
A `spark.readStream.format("orc").load("/path/to/my_folder")` nicely works.

However, I do not want to process the whole table, but rather only start from a certain partition onwards similar to a certain kafka offset.

How can this be implemented? I.e. how can I specify the initial state where to read from.

[Spark Structured Streaming File Source Starting Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391722/spark-structured-streaming-file-source-starting-offset) claims that there is no such feature.
Their suggestion to use: `latestFirst` is not desirable for my use-case, as I do not aim to build an always-on streaming application, but rather use `Trigger.Once` like a batch job with the nice streaming semantics of duplicate reduction and handling of late-arriving data

If this is not available, what would be a suitable workaround?

### edit

> Run warn-up stream with option("latestFirst", true) and
>   option("maxFilesPerTrigger", "1") with checkpoint, dummy sink and huge
>   processing time. This way, warm-up stream will save latest file
>   timestamp to checkpoint.
>
> Run real stream with option("maxFileAge", "0"), real sink using the
>   same checkpoint location. In this case stream will process only newly
>   available files.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/51399134/2587904

building from this idea, let's look at an example:

```
# in bash
rm -rf data
mkdir -p data/dt=20190101
echo "1,1,1" >> data/dt=20190101/1.csv
echo "1,1,2" >> data/dt=20190101/2.csv
mkdir data/dt=20190102
echo "1,2,1" >> data/dt=20190102/1.csv
echo "1,2,2" >> data/dt=20190102/2.csv
mkdir data/dt=20190103
echo "1,3,1" >> data/dt=20190103/1.csv
echo "1,3,2" >> data/dt=20190103/2.csv
mkdir data/dt=20190104
echo "1,4,1" >> data/dt=20190104/1.csv
echo "1,4,2" >> data/dt=20190104/2.csv

spark-shell --conf spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference=true

// from now on in scala
val df = spark.readStream.csv("data")
df.printSchema
val query = df.writeStream.format("console").start
query.stop

// cleanup the data and start from scratch. 
// this time instead of outputting to the console, write to file
val query = df.writeStream.format("csv")
    .option("path", "output")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
val started = query.start


// in bash
# generate new data
mkdir data/dt=20190105
echo "1,5,1" >> data/dt=20190105/1.csv
echo "1,5,2" >> data/dt=20190105/2.csv
echo "1,4,3" >> data/dt=20190104/3.csv

// in scala
started.stop
// cleanup the output, start later on with custom checkpoint
//bash: rm -rf output/*
val started = query.start

// bash
echo "1,4,3" >> data/dt=20190104/4.csv
started.stop

// *****************
//bash: rm -rf output/*
```

Everything works as intended. The operation picks up where the checkpoint marks the last processed file.
How can a checkpoint definition be generated by hands such as all files in `dt=20190101` and `dt=20190102` have been processed and no late-arriving data is tolerated there anymore and the processing shall continue with all the files from `dt=20190103` onwards?

I see that spark generates:

- commits
- metadata
- offsets
- sources
- _spark-metadata

files and folders.
So far I only know that `_spark-metadata` can be ignored to set an initial state / checkpoint.

But have not yet figured out (from the other files) which minimal values need to be present so processing picks up from `dt=20190103` onwards.

### edit 2

By now I know that:

- commits/0 needs to be present
- metadata needs to be present
- offsets needs to be present

but can be very generic:

```
v1
{"batchWatermarkMs":0,"batchTimestampMs":0,"conf":{"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"200"}}
{"logOffset":0}
```

When I tried to remove one of the already processed and committed files from `sources/0/0`, the query still runs but: **not only the new data is processed larger than the existing committed data, but any data**, in particular, the files I just removed from the log.

How can I **change this behavior to only process data more current than the initial state**?

### edit 3

The docs (https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-FileStreamSource.html) but also javadocs ;) list `getOffset`

> The maximum offset (getOffset) is calculated by fetching all the files
>   in path excluding files that start with _ (underscore).

That sounds interesting, but so far I have not figured out how to use it to solve my problem.

Is there a simpler way to achieve the desired functionality besides creating a custom (copy) of the FileSource?

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSource.scala#L237

`maxFileAge` also sounds interesting.

I have started to work on a custom file stream source. However, fail to properly instanciate it. https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/6c0c51e43469ace71550b426cfcce1c1
When calling:

```
val df = spark.readStream.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StatefulFileStreamSource")
    .option("partitionState", "/path/to/data/dt=20190101")
    .load("data")
```

The operation fails with:

```
InstantiationException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StatefulFileStreamSource
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:196)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:30)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:159)
  ... 53 elided
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StatefulFileStreamSource.<init>()
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
  ... 59 more
```

Even though it is basically a copy of the original source. What is different? Why is the constructor not found from https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala#L196? But it works just fine for https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSource.scala#L42

Even:

```
touch -t 201801181205.09 data/dt=20190101/1.csv
touch -t 201801181205.09 data/dt=20190101/2.csv
  val df = spark.readStream
      .option("maxFileAge", "2d")
    .csv("data")
```

returns the whole dataset and fails to filter to the most k current days.

Comment: Not sure if you have already seen the following post. [How to create a custom streaming data source?][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604184/how-to-create-a-custom-streaming-data-source

Comment: Indeed, I do have read this. But as far as I understand `That's the file that links the short name in format to the implementation.`, this registration is only required to use short names. If instead the whole class name is specified,  I should be able to use my custom streaming text file source. But instead there is an issue with the constructor.