# How to read new files uploaded in last one hour using pyspark filestream?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read latest files(say new files in last one hour) available in a directory and load that data . I am trying with pyspark structured streaming. i have tried maxFileAge option of spark streaming, but still it is loading all the files in the diretory, regardless of time specified in the option.

```py
spark.readStream\
.option("maxFileAge", "1h")\
.schema(cust_schema)\
    .csv(upload_path) \
    .withColumn("closing_date", get_date_udf_func(input_file_name()))\
    .writeStream.format('parquet') \
    .trigger(once=True) \
    .option('checkpointLocation', checkpoint_path) \
    .option('path', write_path) \
    .start()
```

Above is the code that i tried, but it will load all available files regardless of time . Please point out what i am doing wrong here ..

Comment: I also tried like answer from this link..ie by creating by warm-up stream..but didn't work for me...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391722/spark-structured-streaming-file-source-starting-offset

Comment: They changed it so that `maxFileAge` will be ignored if `latestFirst` and `maxFilesPerTrigger` are set.  You can set the `cleansource` option to "archive" and it will move the read files to a new location so on your next run they are no longer in your upload_path.

See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to being too late.

`.option("maxFileAge", "1h")` will only work if after the checkpointLocation was created.

Example:

Run first time, read everything.
Run second time, check if checkpointLocation is created then filter by maxFileAge and add these files to `checkpointLocation`.

You can read only a file in readstream with basepath to create a single checkpointLocation, then the maxage param will work in the next batches.

```
spark.readStream\
.option("maxFileAge", "1h")\
.option("basePath", upload_path)\
.schema(cust_schema)\
    .csv(upload_path + "/partition1=xxxx/partition2=yyyy/") \
...
```